# bash extract certain lines from file

Tags: bash

I have file like this:

```
[some_lines_unimportant]
#Field List (hex, dec, bin, char)
00 00 1e 14 0 0 30 20 999909999 000090000 0001-1110
(...)
00 00 3e 01 0 0 62 01 888888888 000088000 0100-1000
[some_lines_unimportant]
```

I would like to be able to extract f.e `3` lines that are under the `#Field list ...` line. How can I do that in bash.

**EDITED:**

this is the file:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ======= Pkt to be transmitted (hex) ================================================
01 00 fe 03 4d 00 00 00 00 02 fe 00 aa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 b8 EOP
# Initiating transfer ...
# ======= Received pkt (hex) =========================================================
02 fe 03 0d 00 fe 00 aa 00 00 00 04 84 00 01 00 10 cc EOP
# ========= Reply pkt fields (hex) ===================================================
  Reply SpW Addr:
02 
# Initiator Log Addr (1 byte), Proto ID (1 byte), Instr (1  byte), Status (1 byte):
fe 03 0d 00 
# Target Log Addr (1 byte), Trans ID (2 bytes MS LS), Reserved (1 byte):
fe 00 aa 00 
# Data Length (3 bytes MS to LS), Header CRC (1 byte):
00 00 04 84 
# Field List (hex, dec, bin, char, [dec line count]):
00 01 00 10    0   1   0  16 0000-0000 0000-0001 0000-0000 0001-0000 . . . . [      1]

# Data CRC (1 byte):
cc
# End of Pkt character:
EOP
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# @@@@@@@@@ Transaction time: 0.225 ms
######### End of online test #########################################################
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` like this, where `-A` specifies how many lines **AFTER** the match:

```
grep -A 3 "^#Field List" file

#Field List (hex, dec, bin, char)
00 00 1e 14 0 0 30 20 999909999 000090000 0001-1110
(...)
00 00 3e 01 0 0 62 01 888888888 000088000 0100-1000
```

Or, if you don't want the first line that matches

```
grep -A 3 "^#Field List" file | sed 1d

00 00 1e 14 0 0 30 20 999909999 000090000 0001-1110
(...)
00 00 3e 01 0 0 62 01 888888888 000088000 0100-1000
```

The circumflex (or hat, `^`) matches the start of the line, i.e. the word `#Field` must be at the very start of the line for it to be matched.

Comment: In the file (before the line I mentioned) I have characters like this `------------------` and it makes grep is throwing an error `unrecognized option`. Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... please click `edit` under your question and make your example file look *exactly* the same as your actual file, also show the command you typed and the error please.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` with the `--after-context`/`-A` argument:

```
grep -A3 '#Field List'
```